# How to perform upgrade on bagisto with laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running laravel bagisto ecommerce...I upgraded laravel from 5.6 to 6, the upgrade went successfully but it complaining about member function get() on null.

Comment: Please show your code as text, not as an image, and show your full class. It's saying that `$this->config` is null, so is `$this->config` defined and populated?

Comment: @aynber I'm really sorry but if this code I'm the one that write it, I could have resolve it, but if u check the image that error is coming from Illuminate/Mail/TransportManager.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have a project using bagisto too and tried to update the laravel to 6,
but consider this big project to be broken while doing a major upgrade thats why they havent dont that untill now in offica release but there is a pull request and a log that webkul upgraded the package to laravel 6 as below :

```
https://github.com/bagisto/bagisto/pull/2082
```

take a look which files were change and do as it to fix the problem . if the problem still exits you can edit question and add more details so people can help you better .